# c# mouse_event does not fire on certain application

Tags: c#, winapi

I am creating a console application that should simulate a click inside a certain application.

Im currently playing around with the external methods, for now i only want the program to click at the current mouse position every second:

```
public class Navigation
{
    private const uint MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE = 0x0001;
    private const uint MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x0002;
    private const uint MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x0004;
    private const uint MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x0008;
    private const uint MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x0010;
    private const uint MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE = 0x8000;

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    static extern bool SetCursorPos(uint x, uint y);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern void mouse_event(uint dwFlags, uint dx, uint dy, uint cButtons, UIntPtr dwExtraInfo);

    private string processName;

    public Navigation(string processName)
    {
        this.processName = processName;
    }

    public void test()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            //SetForegroundWindow(Process.GetProcessesByName(processName)[0].MainWindowHandle);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, UIntPtr.Zero);
            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, UIntPtr.Zero);
        }
    }
}
```

When starting the program and running the test() method the mouse indeed clicks every second, i can move the mouse around the screen and it will click at everything, notepad, spotify etc... EXECPT for the one application that i want to target ...

That is, when i hover the mouse above the particular application i want to click on, nothing happens. I read about putting the target process in the foreground, if i do that the application is put in the foreground but it still does not recieve any clicks.

For example if i hover the mouse above a button inside the application i want to target my program does not click it. When moving the mouse back outside it starts simulating clicks again. Any thoughts?

EDIT: I am following [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/danielggarcia/archive/2014/01/13/simulation-of-mouse-and-keyboard.aspx) tutorial

Comment: @AntonínLejsek Because i want the click to simulate at the current mouse position. Sorry if i wasn't clear

Comment: @AntonínLejsek well i don't know what to tell you, the program does indeed simulate a click at my mouse position every second. Exept for when i hover the target application.

Comment: It's SendInput that you should be using, as is clearly stated in the documentation. Not that using SendInput will solve your problem. Clearly this program doesn't want you to fake its input. Contact the developer of the target app and ask how to automate input to it. Nothing we can do to help.